# Clarity with notice/resignation clause

Tags: resignation, notice-period

I came across this clause on my UK deputation letter.

**Notice Period**:
Your secondment may be terminated by you or XXXXXX America giving 30 days notice to the other. On termination of your secondment you will continue to be employed by XXXXXX North America on the terms of your contract of employment with XXXXXX North America.

By my North America contract, the notice period is 2 months.

Does this mean I have to serve a total of 3 months in notices upon resignation?

Also, the Flight back to North America from the UK will be paid by XXXXXX at the end of your seccondment.

My problem is, I'm relocating to start a new job in France (6 months from now) and I'd rather catch a plane from the UK than California. My employer has a bad habit of screwing with the people who leave (like force them to work extra days) and I have to plan this to work with my Apartment Lease.

Comment: You probably need to talk to HR or to a lawyer.  We don't have access to your agreements nor your company's policy. Voting to close.

Comment: That's the only clause on the contract and company policy on resignation/notice. I could talk to a lawyer, but not to my HR. They're the reason I have to change jobs.

Comment: Then talk to a lawyer. It's a lot more straightforward, less subject to misinterpretation and cheaper to set your feelings aside and clarify with HR instead of fleeing from them, though. Use the money saved to go on a date. Voting to close because you are asking us to interpret a legal agreement, the totality of which we haven't read and because we never put up a shingle claiming legal expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its two months the secondment notice obviously would run in parallel.

Comment: I would hope that this is the correct interpretation. I wouldn't count on it. Ask HR to clarify; that's part of their job... or if you're really terrified of giving any hint that you're considering leaving, take a complete copy of that paperwork to a lawyer.

Comment: Just heard back from the lawyer's office. He said the same thing you did, except that yours was free and his was £475 per hour. I'm not terrified of the HR; I just don't want the slightest hint of my resignation yet.